# How can i populate database when using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using rspec to test my web services but when i looks in my database after each test ,i don't get anything in tables so please help me out to resolve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
**require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "User management", :type => :request do

context "create users" do
  it "creates a user by supplying facebook_token" do
    headers = { "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json",
                "ACCEPT" => ""
     }
    post "/api/users", '{ "user": { "facebook_user_token":"" } }', headers
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end  

end**
```

Comment: Are you using database_cleaner?

Comment: What do you mean "after each test"? Rspec will clear out the database after each test.

Comment: yeah but i need to populate my database for next step of test cases

Answer (score 0):

Basic principle while testing is each test should be independent. No test should depend on the other test.

If you want data in your tables to be used across tests then use

```
context "create users" do
  before :context do
     FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
end
```

Now the user will be available in all the examples inside the context block